# Path from variance of product to product of variance and expectation

Tags: variance

In one paper authors tell:

> We let the initialised elements in $W_l$ be independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.). We assume that the elements in $x_l$ are also i.i.d. and $x_l$ and $W_l$ are independent of each other. Then we have:
>
> $$Var[y_l]=n_lVar[w_lx_l]$$
>
> We let $w_l$ have zero mean. Then the variance of the product of independent variables gives us:
>
> $$Var[y_l] = n_lVar[w_l]E[x_l²]$$

Could someone please describe what might be the way from the first equation to the second?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\operatorname{Var}(w_lx_l)&=\mathbb E[w_l^2x_l^2]-\mathbb E[w_lx_l]^2=\mathbb E[w_l^2]\mathbb E[x_l^2]-\mathbb E[w_l]^2\mathbb E[x_l]^2=\mathbb E[w_l^2]\mathbb E[x_l^2]\\&=\operatorname{Var}(w_l)\mathbb E[x_l^2]\end{align}$$