# Derive Cramer-Rao lower bound for $Var(\hat{\theta})$ given that $\mathbb{E}[\hat{\theta}U]=1$

Tags: variance, inference, expected-value, fisher-information, cramer-rao

I am trying to derive the Cramer-Rao lower bound for $Var(\hat{\theta})$ given that we already know $\mathbb{E}[U]=0$, $Var(U)=I(\theta)$ and $\mathbb{E}[\hat{\theta}U]=1$. I am struggling with using the last fact, I know that the CRLB will be equal to $1/I(\theta)$ but can’t figure out how to use what is given to find this. Is it the correct approach to try and find $Var(U)$ because this is equal to $I(\theta)$? Should I write $\mathbb{E}[\hat{\theta}U]$ as an integral and attempt to use that? I am really stuck here

Comment: The result at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/482142 looks helpful.